# CLion - проблема вывода после запуска кода

Tags: c++, c++11, случайные-числа, clion

Установил CLion на ubuntu. После запуска кода часто выводит на экран некоректные значения. Приходится несколько раз запускать код, чтобы он выдал весь ответ. К примеру: я создал массив из 10 элементов и заполнил его случайными значениями, вывел через цикл на экран. По идее все правильно, но часто выводит не все числа, и чтобы добиться полного вывода массива, надо запускать код несколько раз. Эта проблема относится не только к массивам. Проверил через debugger, все работает отлично, но когда вывожу на экран, часто информация оказывается не корректной.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int *arr, int size) {

    int tmp, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) // i - номер прохода
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) // внутренний цикл прохода
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
                tmp = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int* N = new int;

    cin >> *N;

    int * pArray = new int[*N];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < *N; i++) {
        pArray[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
        cout << pArray[i] << endl;
    }

    bubbleSort(pArray, *N);

    for (int j = 0; j < *N; j++) {
        cout << pArray[j] << " ";
    }

    delete [] pArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: можете приложить пример кода и пример вывода, чтобы не гадать?

Comment: возможно проблема именно с кодом (неинициализированная переменная например).

Comment: К сожалению, проблема осталась. Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема должна быть [решена](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/04/clion-2016-1-2-rc/) в CLion 2016.1.2 RC, просто обновитесь.

Соответствующие заявки на баг-трекере:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6354
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6325

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, поэтому и поставил себе CLion 2016.1.2 RC, с него скриншот и снят. Все так же некоректно выдает результат как и на 2016.1.1

Comment: Проверил, да, вы правы - проблема осталась.

Comment: у clion была другая проблема, с форматированием, тут слегка хитрее все :-) дело - уверен - в неправильной генерации случайных чисел